# Laravel 5.4 and my PHP ver is 7.3 throw an error of count(): Parameter must be an array or an object

Tags: php, laravel, datatables

In a modal, I use to request an `ajax` call with data in data tables it always returns an error like

> "count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements
>   Countable in
>   /var/www/html/proposalwaysTEST/vendor/yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle/src/Engines/CollectionEngine.php"

I am using 7.3 PHP and laravel 5.3..what I can do in this case.

On click, Ajax Request will fire and modal popup results need to be displayed in data tables.

Comment: Please provide some code. Specially your controller.

Comment: check empty for 7.3 PHP, not count

Comment: When looking at that library's (laravel-datatables-oracle) github issues, it seems like you're not the only one with this error:  https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=count%28%29%3A+Parameter+must+be+an+array+or+an+object.

Answer (score -1):

the count function does support null in php 7.2 or greater

use laravel count() like this ("Model::count()")
or use sizoff

Answer (score -1):

reduce your php version to php7.1 and this error can be resolved